# Julia Multicore - Multicore code has strange errors

Tags: multicore, julia

I wrote the following code, and it makes sense to me but it is outputting a bunch of random stuff and also going slower than a single core implementation. The way the code works is it creates a vector of remote references with the size equal to the number of cores on the computer and then it takes the integral that needs to be done and divides it up into segments such that the number of integrals to be done is equal to the number of cores. It then assigns a remote reference to each of the integrals and allows them to process each segment on a different core. These are then combined at the end in the summation loop. Without further ado here is the offending code.

```
function multiquadgk(F,xMin,xMax)
  procs=nworkers()
  results=Array(RemoteRef,1,procs)
  bnds=linspace(xMin,xMax,procs+1)
  for i = 1:(procs)
    #println("Starting Process")
    #println(i)
    results[i]=@spawn quadgk(F,bnds[i],bnds[i+1])[1]
  end
  sum1=0
  for i=results
    #println("Results for Each integration step")
    #println(fetch(i))
    sum1+=fetch(i)
  end
  return sum1
end
```

For some reason it include random output such as:

```
Loading help data...
    From worker 2:  Loading help data...
    From worker 3:  Loading help data...
    From worker 3:  0196.290571870170
    From worker 3:  98.145285935085
    From worker 3:  196.29057187017
    From worker 2:  0196.290571870170
    From worker 2:  98.145285935085
    From worker 2:  196.29057187017
    From worker 3:  -.0005038237605425529
    From worker 3:  .3255338699535369
    From worker 3:  324.8745134499407
    From worker 3:
```

What does this output mean and how do I silence it once I my code works?

Also it seems that the code seems be just be executing the exact same thing twice on both cores...I can't see any reason why that would be happening.

Also any tips on methods for multicore techniques would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: what is your `versioninfo`? this works fine for me (with simple `mutiquadgk(x->x^2,-10,10)` at least)

Comment: I allowed linux mint to auto update so I am running julia 0.3.0

Comment: well it would be helpful to have more context. what is the full function call and definition of `F`?